# Accordion List Links Dont Work

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have code below for an accordion list I am creating using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am just wondering why links do not work once I put them inside the accordion list? I cant see what I did wrong. Anything helps, cheers.

```js
(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }
  var classie = {
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(classie);
  } else {
    window.classie = classie;
  }
})(window);

var $ = function(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

var accordion = $('.accordion');
accordion.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if (classes) {
      for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if (classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
          var title = e.target;
          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
          classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');
          if (classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
            if (classie.has(content, 'animateOut')) {
              classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'animateIn');
          } else {
            classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
            classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
          }
          classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #005bab;
}
.accordion dl {} .bottombar {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00688B;
}
.accordion dt > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #005bab;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion dd {
  background-color: #f4f8fc;
  color: #30353d;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.accordion dd > p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
}
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e1ecf7;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #e2ecf6;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.accordionTitle:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #005bab;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover {
  background-color: #e8f0f7;
}
.accordionTitleActive {
  background-color: #e8f0f7;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media all {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 100em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s;
    transition: max-height 1.5s;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 50em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}
.accordionItemCollapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}
.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt>
        <a class="accordionTitle" href="#"> 
        <span style="color: #005bab;">Heading One</span></a>
      </dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
      </dd>
      <div class="bottombar"> &#160;</div>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines bind an event listener to the containing `.accordion` element which prevents the default action anytime anything inside is clicked:

```
var accordion = $('.accordion');
accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

If you either bind that to `.accordionTitle`, or move them further down after the class checks (so you only block propagation and prevent default if it's the element you want) then the link works.